# meaning of "written-out number"

Tags: word-usage

An answerer suggests

> Yes, once you fill in the blanks (teams, post-season). I think you need a **written-out number** at the start of a sentence.

I understand the meaning of "written-out", that is,

> to write especially in a full and complete form.

What does "written-out number" mean?

I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1097&bih=559&sxsrf=ALeKk00gG_oOZkbLOK9Ef0RQFpTFJHpoIQ%3A1587105961935&ei=qVCZXq3SOMji-AbQh4GgCA&q=meaning%20of%20%22written-out%20number%22&oq=meaning%20of%20%22written-out%20number%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCCMQrgIQJzoECAAQRzoECAAQHkoKCBcSBjEyLTEzMkoICBgSBDEyLTVQhQVY2jdg4jloAXACeACAAd8BiAH6BJIBAzItM5gBAKABAaABAqoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjtytO47u7oAhVIMd4KHdBDAIQQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) it and went through top hits. None gives a clear explanation of it. [One of them](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-573577.html) gives

> "2,002,102"
>
> Two million and two thousand and one hundred and two

Could someone please give a hint about **the rules/conventions of it**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally understand "written-out number" to mean a number written in words and not in numerals.  So "seven" instead of "7".

Many style guides suggest that numbers that are part of a sentence should be written out. So you should write

> I have three sisters.

But you can use numerals for money, measurements, page references and mathematical expressions. Large exact numbers or long decimals and vulgar fractions can be written as numerals.

> I have £20.  See page 234. There have been 2,438,180 reported cases.

It is inconvenient to start a sentence with a numeral, since it can't be capitalised.  You often are able to rephrase, or write out the number.

> Five hundred metres from my house is a little cottage.
>
> There is a little cottage 500 metres from my house.

The exact way of expressing a number varies according to dialect. Generally you split into groups of three and give each group as 
"X hundred and Y"

> 583,052,112
>
> five hundred and eighty-three million,
>   fifty-two thousand,
>   one hundred and twelve.

If the number is more than 1000 but the hundreds digit is zero you need an extra "and"

> 60045
>
> sixty thousand
>   and forty-five

This is also a fairly common toy problem for learning computer programming. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504350/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-python

And you can generate infinite examples with python, in the dialect of your choice.

https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words

Comment: Can we say "spelled-out number" ?

Comment: We very very rarely have to say anything.  If you need to you should say "The number written in words"  You occasionally see this as an instruction on "how to write a cheque".  But nobody every writes cheques any more so, you really never have to say this.

Comment: Thank you so much.